# Changing button text doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, button

I am having a problem with changing a button text. My application has 2 buttons. Button A accesses the internal memory/SDCARD directories on the phone(Filechooser activity). Once a file is selected, the filename of the selected file is stored in a Set list. Each file selected is stored in the set. At the same time, there is a variable counter that increments whenever a file is selected. The other button is the "Selected" button which display a ListView of the selected files. The problem is whenever I attempt to change the text for the Selected button so that it shows how many items was selected, the application crashes.

i.e: if 8 items were selected, the Selected button should be replaced with the text "Selected(8)".

Here is the code:

```
private void onFileClick(Option o){

    selected.add(o.getName());
    itemSelected = selected.size();
    selectedList.setText("Selected("+itemSelected+")"); // the problem

}
```

Please if anyone can figure out a way to change that button text I would appreciate that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the stack trace you get when your application crashes.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.test.Filechooser.update(Filechooser.java:114)
at com.example.test.Filechooser.onFileClick(Filechooser.java:101)
at com.example.test.Filechooser.onListItemClick(Filechooser.java:92)
at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)

Comment: at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You should provide more code of your application. There is NullPointerExcpetion in line 101 which means that one of the objects you are referring to in onFileClick method is null. Which one is in 101 line?

Comment: it's 

    selectedList.setText("Selected("+itemSelected+")");

selectedList is the button which text I want to change. itemsSelected is an integer which stores "selected.size()" each time someone clicks on a file. selected is a set list which stores the filename(o.getName()) of all selected files.

Comment: I am decalring the button as such "Button selectedList = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);" and it's a global variable.

Comment: Are you calling setContentView before you do findViewbyId?

Comment: Nope. setContentView is not in the Filechooser class.

Comment: I fixed it. Lame mistake can happen to anyone :P